# Deeplink doesn't works with applicationIdSuffix

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, deep-linking, android-build-type

I actually need a break point.

My deeplinks work well with my package name com.app.test.
However, when I tried to separate my debug build with my release by an applicationIdSuffix like ".debug". The deeplinks go KO even if I done the association link between my app and my website. My application in debug still can't support it.
Someone have an idea about working with deeplink with an applicationIdSuffix in build.gradle?

My android manifest

```
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*.app.test.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/profile"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And inside the build.gradle.kts

```
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
```

The thing is: it's worked perfect without the suffix. So I just wanna find out how to make it works with suffix

My associate file:

```
{
"relation": [
  "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
],
"target": {
  "namespace": "android_app",
  "package_name": "com.app.test.debug",
  "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
    "AD:E5:84:1C:97:95:45:EA:8E:1B:75:39:C7:AA:ED:37:D4:E6:B1:A2:49:B5:CC:9E:97:5C:A8:29:6Q:6B:63:3E",
    "60:10:E9:E3:DA:4E:CD:37:7A:3F:B8:B0:E8:EB:10:2D:12:E6:36:BA:0A:50:44:FF:A6:FC:6C:65:CE:56:0D:67",
    "0F:E3:98:3F:B2:A1:F1:DD:1C:AB:7A:3C:6E:8A:48:65:BA:BA:BA:21:22:E6:41:B9:81:17:5D:B8:61:E5:C3:B9"
  ]
}
```

},

Thanks

Comment: Post the deeplink you're trying to use, and the intent filter in the manifest

Comment: Done. Nothing special

Answer (score 0):

The declared website association is linked to an app id + certificate. Include your additional debug app id and the corresponding certificate fingerprint (possibly the debug certificate).

The naming might be a bit confusing. Note that:

> package_name: The application ID declared in the app's build.gradle
> file.

Multiple entries in the `assetlinks.json` file can be added [like this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#multiple-apps):

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example.puppies.app",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"]
  }
  },
  {
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example.monkeys.app",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"]
  }
}]
```

Comment: already done. But still not working. That's why I'm still have a big headache.